# Node JS save user input into a text file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a local server running with `Node JS`. Then I have several `select` tags and I want after the user chooses, to save their inout on a text file? Could somebody help me out how to do this? (furthermore, when I press submit I get an undefined on the terminal)

The node js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/server'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname +'/images'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('main.html');
});

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('server is running on ' + port);
});

app.post('/submit', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body.rank);
});
```

The HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="/submit"  > <!--action-page.php-->

        <select name="option" size="1" style="width:80px;" required id="rankx">
          <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Option</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>

      <br />
        <select name="option" size="1" style="width:80px;" required>
          <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Rank</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem 1

> ```
> app.use(bodyParser.json());
> ```

Your form is submitting data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, not JSON.

You need a body parser that can handle `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

See [`bodyParser.urlencoded([options])`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions)

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
```

## Problem 2

You have inputs named `option` and `submit` but you are looking for one named `rank`.

You have to match your input names to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code inside the node js file

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded\
```